# Hide Toolbar on login component without having to refresh (Angular 11)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I created a simple Authentication service that works well at the start of the web app , however in a user-case scenario where the user decides to log-out and relog-in the toolbar/navbar remain visible when switching back to the login page, in order for it to become invisible the page needs to be refreshed so the `ngIf` method would work; my idea was to show the toolbar/navbar whenever the user is logged in, which means if there is a token cached in localStorage.

> this is the code that applies the toolbar/navbar

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="main" >
    <mat-toolbar  *ngIf="userToken">
      <div class="MenuBar">
        
          <button mat-icon-button style="margin:auto" color="primary" (click)="opened=!opened" aria-label="Example icon button with a menu icon">
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
          </button>
        
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home</button>
      </div> 
      
        <span class="spacer"></span>
        <button mat-stroked-button id="Users" style="margin-right: 16px" routerLink="/users" routerLinkActive="active">Profile</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent"  (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
      
    </mat-toolbar>
 
    
    <mat-sidenav-container class="container" >
      <mat-sidenav mode="push"  [(opened)]=opened >
      <p>Working</p>
      </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content>
          <div class="app-container">
            <alert></alert>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </div>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
      
    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component,ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

import { AccountService } from '../app/services/account.service';
import { User } from '../app/models/user';
import { Token } from '@angular/compiler/src/ml_parser/lexer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FrontEnd';
  userToken: Token;
 
  opened=false;
  

    constructor(private accountService : AccountService) {
      this.userToken = this.accountService.userToken;
        
        
    }

    
    logout() {
      
      this.accountService.logout();
      
    }

}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './authentification/login/login.component'
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { UsersModule } from './Users CRUD/users.module';
import { AuthGuard } from './_helpers/auth.guard';

const authModule=()=> import('./authentification/authentification.module').then(x => x.AuthentificationModule);
const usersModule = () => import('./Users CRUD/users.module').then(x => x.UsersModule);


const routes: Routes = [
  { path : '', component: MainComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'users', loadChildren: usersModule, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path : 'auth',loadChildren: authModule},

  { path : '**', redirectTo:''}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**account.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { User } from '../models/user';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AccountService {
    private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    public user: Observable<User>;
    readonly BaseURL ='https://localhost:44381/api';
    public subj = new BehaviorSubject({});


    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {
        this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
        this.user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
        
    }

    public get userToken() {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('user')));
    }

    login(username, password) {
        return this.http.post<User>(`${this.BaseURL}/User/Login`, { username, password });
           /* .pipe(map(user => {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
                this.userSubject.next(user);
                return user;
            }));*/
    }


    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage and set current user to null
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        this.userSubject.next(null);
        this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
    }

    GetUser()
    {
        return this.http.get(this.BaseURL+'/UserProfile');
    }

    register(user: User) {
        return this.http.post(`${this.BaseURL}/User/Register`, user);
    }

    getAll() {
        return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.BaseURL}/users`);
    }

    getById(id: string) {
        return this.http.get<User>(`${this.BaseURL}/UserProfile/${id}`);
    }

  
}
```

Comment: We know nothing about your authentication module. First, are you sure that the logout method clears, i.e. the token is actually of falsy value (null or undefined)? Perhaps the token stays there and some other flag is changed. Or perhaps the token becomes an empty object, which is not a falsy value? Maybe there is some observable you can hook up to instead?

Comment: @TotallyNewb everything works fine ! it's just that the toolbar remains visible and i have to refresh the page for it to become invisible

Comment: Which would indicate that there's no subscription present (ie. your `userToken` doesn't realize that `accountService.userToken` has changed). I suggest you share your `accountService` code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kin I was able to understand the code better and come up with a solution to my problem.
I Fixed this by setting the user token in localstorage inside the `login` method in the `service.ts` file then subscribing to the user in the `component.ts` file
here's the code :

*account.service.ts*

```
...
login(username, password) {
        return this.http.post<User>(`${this.BaseURL}/User/Login`, { username, password }).pipe(map(user => {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('user', user.token);
            this.userSubject.next(user);
            return user;
        }));
    }
...
```

*app.component.ts*

```
...
constructor(private accountService : AccountService) {
      
      this.accountService.user.subscribe(x => this.user = x);
        
    }
...
```

*app.component.html*

```
<div class="main" >
    <mat-toolbar  *ngIf="user" >
      <div class="MenuBar">
        
          <button mat-icon-button style="margin:auto" color="primary" (click)="opened=!opened" >
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
          </button>
        
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" (click)="opened=false">Home</button>
      </div> 
      
        <span class="spacer"></span>
        <button mat-stroked-button id="Users" style="margin-right: 16px" routerLink="/users" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="opened=false">Profile</button>
        <button mat-raised-button color="accent"  (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
      
    </mat-toolbar>
 
    
    <mat-sidenav-container  >
      <mat-sidenav mode="push"  [(opened)]=opened >
      <p>Working</p>
      </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content>
          <div class="app-container">
            <alert></alert>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </div>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
      
    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

> I hope this helps anyone with a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is clear the userToken when user logout

```
// app.component.ts
logout() {
    this.userToken = null;
    this.accountService.logout();
}
```

The best practice is use [behavior subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject#behaviorsubject) to store your userToken.
Behavior subject is an object of RxJS.

#### 20210309 update

The userToken is assigned inside of the constructor function of app.component.ts, which means it is only evaluated when Angular initialize appComponent.

So userToken is fixed after appCompoent initialized.

If you want to change userToken dynamically, you can subscribe the userSubject of AccountService.

#### 20210310 update

It is the concept of RxJX, you can checkout the tutorial of RxJS.

```
// wherever component the login function in 
public login(userObj){
    this.accountService.userSubject.next(userObj);
}
```

```
// app.component.ts
private user$: Subscription;
ngOnInit(){
    this.user$ = this.accountService.userSubject.subscribe((user)=>{
        this.userToken = user;
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.user$.unsubscrible();
}
```

Comment: ```logout() {
       
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        this.userSubject.next(null);
        this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
    }```                                                                                                                                              this is my logout method and it works fine the problem is with the 'ngIf' it only works on page refresh

Comment: @SkanderKratou, I mean clear the userToken in the logout function of appComponent, not the one in accountService. Also, I update the answer after seeing your accountService.

Comment: I see ! I updated my logout method in the 'app.component.ts' and it fixed it however the issue remains with the login scenario , the toolbar doesn't show up. I didn't really understand how to implement the dynamic userToken change

Comment: @SkanderKratou, It is the concept of RxJX, you can checkout the tutorial of RxJS.